# Get multidimensional post array via Yii getPost function

Tags: post, yii, frameworks

If i have a $_POST array as follows:

```
$_POST['request']['type']['user'] = 'abc';
```

How would I access this same variable using the Yii::app()->request->getPost() functionality built into Yii 1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sussed it..

```
Yii::app()->request->getPost('request');
echo $request['type']['user'];
```

Comment: Vote up for solving it yourself, and posting the solution.